# How do i get my output to print row rise instead of horizontally?

Tags: python, binary, bitwise-operators

I am having trouble to get the desired output for my bitwise operation. For this project I am only using logical and or operators and not using bitwise operators to compute the result. Is there any method I can use?

```
def main():
    expression = input("Enter binary expression: ")
    binary1,operator,binary2 = expression.split(" ")
    result = ""

    for i in range(0,len(binary1)):
        if (operator == "&"):
           result = int(binary1[i] and int(binary2[i]))
        print("Result is: ", result)
    
main()
```

Current results:

```
Enter binary expression: 1011 & 0011
Result is: 0
Result is: 0
Result is: 1
Result is: 1
```

Expected results:

```
Enter binary expression: 1011 & 0011
Result is: 0011
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the results in a list and print when you are done looping:

```
result = []

for i in range(0,len(binary1)):
    if (operator == "&"):
       result.append(int(binary1[i] and int(binary2[i])))

print("Result is: ", "".join(map(str, result)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already created a variable by `result = ""`, but you are not actually using it. You can just convert the value to string and add it back to the `result` variable at each iteration, and instead of printing  it each iteration, print it after exiting from the loop:

```py
def main():
    expression = input("Enter binary expression: ")
    binary1, operator, binary2 = expression.split(" ")
    result = ""
    
    for i in range(0, len(binary1)):
        if (operator == "&"):
            result += str(int(binary1[i] and int(binary2[i]))) #<--concatenate to result
    print("Result is: ", result)   #<-- Print outside the loop
main()
```

#### SAMPLE RUN

```py
Enter binary expression: >? 1011 & 0011
Result is:  0011
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate string variable and concatenate the result:

```
expression = input("Enter binary expression: ")
binary1,operator,binary2 = expression.split(" ")
result = ""
finalExpression = ""

for i in range(0,len(binary1)):
   if (operator == "&"):
      result = int(binary1[i] and int(binary2[i]))
      finalExpression += str(result)

print("Result is: ", finalExpression)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `end=` parameter of the print function.  This allows you to decide what `print()` will use as an end of line character (nothing in this case):

```
def main():
    expression = input("Enter binary expression: ")
    binary1,operator,binary2 = expression.split(" ")
    # result = ""  # not needed

    print("Result is: ",end="")  # start of line (stay on same print line)
    
    for i in range(0,len(binary1)):
        if (operator == "&"):
           result = int(binary1[i] and int(binary2[i]))
        print(result,end="") # print one bit, stay on same line
        
    print() # end of line when done
    
main()
```

output:

```
Enter binary expression: 1011 & 0011
Result is: 0011
```